# ASP.NET MVC4 Generalized Field Initialization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, query-string, request.querystring

In ASP.NET MVC4, I want to initialize fields with values. When the user gets the page, before he has posted it back, I want to have it start out with values in some fields. The values will be drawn from the query string, not hard coded. Say a user is filling out a form: He's logged in, you know his name and address. As a courtesy, make those the default values. Doesn't matter where they come from, really, except that it's a set of key-value pairs, and the values are strings. I just want to put something in fields without the user posting the form first and I'd really like to do it without hard-coding a long, long list of assignments to every property in a rather complicated model.

Right now it's done in a JS loop in `$(document).ready()`, but it belongs on the server. I'd like to replicate that logic, though: Treat the query param names as unique identifiers.

In the `Index()` method of my controller, I tried calling `ModelState.TrySetModelValue()` (which when `ModelState` is populated, identifies each field by one unique string) but at this stage, `ModelState` is empty, so of course that didn't work. I tried changing Index() to expect an instance of the model as a parameter, but that doesn't help.

Must I rewrite every `@Html.EditorFor()`/`TextBoxFor()`/etc. call in the application? That seems crazy. Properly, this is something I'd do in a loop, in one place, not scattered around in multiple spots in each of a growing number of views.

I have a feeling that I'm failing to grasp something fundamental about the way MVC4 is intended to work.

**UPDATE 2**

It turns out that if you decorate your action method with `[HttpGet]`, and you have it expect the model as a parameter, then if you use the field *names* (`foo.bar`) rather than IDs (`foo_bar`) in the query string, it does what I want automatically. `ModelState` is populated. I must not have had the action method decorated with `[HttpGet]` when I looked at `ModelState`.

If a field is set via query string automatically, that supersedes whatever's in your model. That's reasonable; the whole point is to override the model's default values. But if you want to in turn override possible query string values (e.g., say there's a checkbox for an "electronic signature"; that should always require an explicit effort on the user's part), then you've got to do that via `ModelState`.

That means that my first solution, below, had no actual effect (*provided I had the `[HttpGet]` property on the action method*). It only set properties of the model which had already been set in `ModelState` by the framework, and whose values in the model were therefore ignored.

What's a little bit stranger is that `ModelState` gives fields a different key if they're *not* in the query string. `foo.bar.baz` uses just that as a key if it's in the query string, but if it isn't, the key becomes `foo.footypename.bar.bartypename.baz`. There appears to be an exception if the property's name is the same as it's type: I have a `Name` model class, and another model class has a property `public Name Name { get; set }`. Properties of type `Name`, which are *named* name, are never followed by their type name in the `ModelState` keys. However, I have not yet ruled out other possible reasons for that particular property having its typename excluded. That's a guess. The typenames are excluded for "leaf" properties in all cases in my model. Is that because they're types known to the system, or "leaves", or what? I don't know.

In any case, a leaf property of the "root" class of the model always uses its own name as a key in `ModelState`.

So the generalized answer is you assign to the model. But there's a different specific answer for initialization from a query string.

**UPDATE**

Solution -- much code snipped

```
//  Controller base
public abstract class ControllerBase<TModel> : Controller 
{
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult Index(TModel model)
    {
        HttpContext.Request.QueryString.CopyTo(model);

        return View("Index", model);
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Given NameValueCollection of keys/values in the form 
    /// "foo.bar.baz" = "text", and an object which is the *parent* of
    /// foo, set properties of foo accordingly. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="src"></param>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    public static void CopyTo<T>(this NameValueCollection src, T target)
    {
        String strkey;
        Object objval;

        foreach (var key in src.Keys)
        {
            strkey = "" + key;
            objval = src[strkey];

            target.TrySetPropertyValue(strkey, objval);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Given a reference to an object objThis, the string "foo.bar.baz", 
    /// and an object o of a type optimistically hoped to be convertible 
    /// to that of objThis.foo.bar.baz, set objThis.foo.bar.baz = o
    ///
    /// If foo.bar is null, it must have a default constructor, or we fail 
    /// and return false. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objThis"></param>
    /// <param name="propPathName"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool TrySetPropertyValue(this object objThis, 
                                           string propPathName, object value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propPathName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(propPathName);
        }
        var names = propPathName.Split(new char[] { '.' }).ToList();

        var nextPropInfo = objThis.GetType().GetProperty(names.First());

        if (null == nextPropInfo)
            return false;

        if (names.Count > 1)
        {
            var nextPropValue = nextPropInfo.GetValue(objThis, null);

            if (null == nextPropValue)
            {
                nextPropValue = Activator
                    .CreateInstance(nextPropInfo.PropertyType);
                nextPropInfo.SetValue(objThis, nextPropValue);
            }

            names.RemoveAt(0);

            return nextPropValue.TrySetPropertyValue(
                                     String.Join(".", names), value);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                var conv = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor
                               .GetConverter(nextPropInfo.PropertyType);
                value = conv.ConvertFrom(value);

                nextPropInfo.SetValue(objThis, value);
            }
            catch (System.FormatException)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `EditorFor` is a cheap way to prototype, but IMO not suitable for any production application. As for using `TextBoxFor`, `DropDownListFor`, etc....yes, that's pretty much central to how MVC views are constructed.

Comment: @Yuck I don't mind using TextBoxFor etc. at all. I like 'em a lot (the ones that work correctly -- HiddenFor doesn't). I just prefer not to scatter the implementation of this one little feature around among every call to every one of those things in, eventually, a couple dozen different views. Ugly (edited above to mention that). The views aren't where it belongs. What if we want to turn it off, or change the way it behaves? I'm not married to EditorFor. I replace it with more specific helpers as the need arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize your model in controller with default values and then use it like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Name)
```

Initialization in Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   MyModel model = new MyModel();
   model.Name = "myname";
   return View("myview", model);
}
```

You can also set the attributes in TextBoxFor

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Name, new { value = "myname"})
```

**Update**

If your url looks like `mysite/Edit?id=123` try decalring your controller action like

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id) 
{ ...
```

Also try decorating it with `HttpPost` or `HttpGet` attribute

Comment: This doesn't take into account querystring values.

Comment: @Yuck the OP said "Doesn't matter where they come from, really  I just want to put something in fields without the user posting the form first". So it's totally fine to initialize model's properties with values in controller and pass the instance to the view.

Comment: *The values will be drawn from the query string, not hard coded.*

Comment: @Yuck yes, and after that he said that I've quoted.

Comment: @VladL I ended up initializing the model from QueryString much as you suggest. Unfortunately there was a fair degree of reflection code involved in making that happen in a loop, rather than hard-coding a large and maintenance-intensive list of `foo.bar.baz = HttpContext.Request.QueryString["foo.bar.baz"]`. I don't know if I stressed sufficiently that I wanted to do it in a loop -- but I did mention it twice, and the mention of `TrySetModelState()` is hardly inconsistent with it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett your code doesn't look efficient, but I don't really know how your url is constructed. If your url looks like mysite/Edit?id=123 try decalring your controller action like `public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{ ...` Also try decorating it with HttpPost or HttpGet attribute

Comment: @VladL That's interesting. I was using the field IDs (underscore) rather than field names (dot) for convenience in doing this in JS, and so I never noticed that IF I have Index() expect TModel as a parameter, and it's marked `[HttpGet]` (which it actually was!), and if I use the names (dot)... it does what I want AUTOMAGICALLY. Boy, do i feel stupid! Thank you!